# If clause with both sentences in simple past

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Knowing the standard rules for *if clauses* I have always wondered whether some speakers just use the if part as if (no pun intended) it were a non-conditional sentence.

I am just watching a movie and have the following example:

> If you knew then why did you...

where the speaker finds out that the other person had known that the victim was innocent but still punished him despite this knowledge.

So obviously both things happened in the past - not only grammatically but actually.

**My question**
When is this non-standard form used? Is it informal? Is it American English (they sometimes say things like "If I would..." and this is also an American movie)? And how is this form called grammatically?

Comment: I don't understand what "non-standard" refers to here - the example is *normal use of English*. Are you suggesting there's some other form that you think is "more standard"? If so, what? You're surely not suggesting that *If you **had known** then why did you...* is the "normal, most common" form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, it is the grammatically correct form anyway, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Arguably past perfect could be ***a*** "grammatically correct" form in your context, but I'm not even sure about that. Note that it would be both "valid" *and* "normal" in a context such as *If you **had** known I was coming then surely you'd have baked a cake*, but that certainly wouldn't sound good to me with *...then why didn't you bake a cake?*

Comment: @Closevoter: What is the reason for the vote? How can the question be improved? Thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Ok, fair enough... perhaps a moderator could transfer it. Will you flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: We now have the ability to *vote* for migration to ELL, rather than flagging for moderator attention and *asking* for it. So I assume that we're *supposed* to use that method (not because the mods are "lazy" or "overworked", but because ideally SO would like all their sites to work with minimal mod intervention; we the *users* are supposed to look after things wherever possible).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: How to do that? I don't see it. How much reputation do you need for that?

Comment: **Close -> Off Topic because... -> This question belongs on another site on the Stack Exchange network** (then you can select either ELU.meta or ELL as the "correct" site). I think if you have the 3K rep required to closevote at all, all possible reasons are available.

Comment: *if I would have* is one of my biggest grammar peeves.

Comment: @shawnt00: Are you are native speaker?

Comment: @vonjd Yes I am.

Comment: @shawnt00: I think many people say it in the US, no matter the educational level.

Comment: @vonjd Sadly it is very common. I agree that includes educated people just as much as anybody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is actually perfectly standard.

English conditionals can be either *open* or *remote*:

- In a *remote* conditional, the if-clause presents a hypothesis that is presupposed to be false. According to traditional grammar, the if-clause then uses either the past subjunctive (with the main clause being in the present conditional) or the pluperfect subjunctive (with the main clause being in the conditional perfect). For example:

  - Present time: "If he were here, I'd be happier." (This is sometimes called a "second conditional".)
  - Past time: "If he'd been here, I'd have been happier." (This is sometimes called a "third conditional".)
- In an *open* conditional, the if-clause presents a hypothesis that is held to be possible, or perhaps even true. In this case, its tense follows the normal rules for selecting a tense in adverbial subordinate clauses. For example:

  - Future time: "If you're here tomorrow, please talk to him." (This is sometimes called a "first conditional".)
  - Present time: "If he's not here right now, then he's late." (Ditto.)
  - Past time: "If he wasn't *here* yesterday, then where was he?" (This doesn't have a numerical name, but it's perfectly standard.)

(Hat-tip to https://literalminded.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/if-i-had-known/ for explaining the relationship of the "first/second/third conditional" terminology to, um, reality.)

Answer (score 1):

It is neither nonstandard nor informal, i.e. it is appropriate in both formal and informal speech. ***If*** is in this case equivalent to ***if it is true that***:

> If it is true that you knew then why…

Michael Swan (Practical English Usage, OUP, 1998, p. 258) gives the following example:

> If you were in Boston, why didn’t you come and see us?